# Symfony2 - Can doctrine:migrations:diff create DB-agnostic code instead of SQL?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-migrations

Running `php app/console doctrine:migrations:diff` generates a new migration class as required to translate the current database schema to that specified by changes to entities.

This example shows such a generated class for creating a `fos_user` table:

```
class Version20120712145445 extends AbstractMigration
{
    public function up(Schema $schema)
    {
        $this->abortIf($this->connection->getDatabasePlatform()->getName() != "mysql");        
        $this->addSql("CREATE TABLE fos_user (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, ...);
    }

    public function down(Schema $schema)
    {
        $this->abortIf($this->connection->getDatabasePlatform()->getName() != "mysql");        
        $this->addSql("DROP TABLE fos_user");
    }
}
```

As you can see, this the generated migration is tied to a specific database server, that being MySQL in this instance.

I'd like to use an in-memory sqlite database in test environments due to the (expected) performance benefits reducing test execution time.

I could take the above generated SQL and translate that into `$table = $schema->createTable(); $table->addColumn();` equivalents, however doing so is both time consuming and invites the introduction of errors due to a poor human translation of SQL to code.

**Can the doctrine:migrations:diff command create platform-agnostic migration code instead of the above platform-specific SQL?**

Comment: I think the answer is no, not yet... And anyway, the diff tool should only be a nice-to-have and should not avoid the developer to write himself his migration classes. But still, I agree that this would be a nice feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that is not possible with the current versions. If you need database agnostic migrations you should take a look at [LiquiBase](http://www.liquibase.org/) for migrations. There is a Symfony2 Bundle for LiquiBase too [LiquibaseBundle](https://github.com/RtxLabs/LiquibaseBundle)

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no support for other database migration tools but they are planning to support some database management tools

see [doctrine: DBAL-602](http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DBAL-602) this ticket is a feature-request for LiquiBase, DBDeploy and phinx support for doctrine migrations